# CSS : Create Process Steps Style

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to CSS.

I want to create a Process Step Like in the image.

[image]

Below is the code I have tried.

```css
.inline-div{
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 0.04rem gray solid;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
}


.active{
  background: #8b7b38;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="inline-div">Text A</div>
    <div class="inline-div active">Text B</div>
    <div class="inline-div">Text C</div>
</div>
```

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: You did pretty well. What is your problem here?

Comment: there are 2 borders between 2 steps. like right border of 1st step and left border of 2nd step is mixing. and there is a gap between each steps.

Comment: Please add a clarity image in the question.

Comment: I have this image only. that's why it's blurred.

Answer (score 2):

try this instead,

Remove the gap between each process by using flex

```
.main{ 
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  display: flex;
}
```

And to remove all border-left of inline-div except first item.

```
.inline-div:not(:first-child){
  margin-left:-0.04rem; // to remove the left border 
}
```

```css
.inline-div{
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 0.04rem gray solid;
  width: 25%;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
}
.inline-div:not(:first-child){
  margin-left:-0.04rem; // to remove the left border 
}
.main{ 
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  display: flex;
}

.active{
  background: #8b7b38;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.inline-div {}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="inline-div">Text A</div>
    <div class="inline-div active">Text B</div>
    <div class="inline-div">Text C</div>
    <div class="inline-div">Text D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. There are 2 borders between 2 steps.  like right border of 1st step and left border of 2nd step is mixing. How can I get rid of it ?

Comment: `margin-left:-0.04rem;`  here using `0.04rem` its is the border-width to negelete by using -0.04rem.

Comment: `.inline-div:not(:first-child)` get all inline-div except the first item.

Answer (score 1):

set outer div's `font-size` to zero to remove the gap between each 2 steps, set right step's `margin-left` to negative border width to overlap left step's border, then it'll work fine:

```css
.outer-div{
    font-size: 0;
}

.inline-div{
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 0.04rem gray solid;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25%;
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px; /* set inner div's font-size as you need */
}


.active{
  background: #8b7b38;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.no-left-border{
  margin-left: -0.04rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-div">
    <div class="inline-div">Text A</div>
    <div class="inline-div active no-left-border">Text B</div>
    <div class="inline-div no-left-border">Text C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.inline-div{
      padding: 1rem;
      border: 0.04rem gray solid;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 25%;
      border-top-left-radius: 25px;
      background-color: transparent;
    }
    
    
    .active{
      background: #8b7b38;
      color: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .flex-div {
      display: flex;
      background: blue; // change to your color
    }
```

```html
<div class="flex-div">
        <div class="inline-div">Text A</div>
        <div class="inline-div active">Text B</div>
        <div class="inline-div">Text C</div>
    </div>
```